# imageWithContentsOfFile does not work with iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, iphone-5

I am making an application for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 compatibility. For setting the image I am using the code:
`[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaaa" ofType:@"png"]]]`

1. It works fine for iPhone 4 simulator and device, but does not work on iPhone5 simulator. I dont have an iPhone 5 yet. can any body tell me, will it work on iPhone 5 device?
2. If I use a different name for the image to be used for iPhone 5, and I donot write @2x with the image name, then `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaaa" ofType:@"png"]]]` works fine oniphone 5 simulator. Can any body tell me, will it work on iPhone 5 device also?
3. Or is there any other way out to set the images on iPhone 5 using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaaa" ofType:@"png"]]]`.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: just try to print the resource path [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aaaa" ofType:@"png"]] and make sure its not nil

Comment: Its printing the path. As its working for iPhone 4. It works for iPhone 5 if I write the image name as aaaa.png@2x in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That works for iPhone 5 device also. Just copy the image with a different name.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
        [appConfig setLogoURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"file://localhost", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"header5" ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
    else {
        [appConfig setLogoURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"file://localhost", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"header" ofType:@"png"]]];
    }
}
else {
        [appConfig setLogoURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"file://localhost", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"header" ofType:@"png"]]];
}
```